# How do I use the pages in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

1) I'm using WordPress as a CMS for a site. Therefore I want to use the Pages instead of the Posts. When I add a new page, it will create it at an address like "http://localhost/new_mtt/about-us", but when I click on View Page, it goes to the 404 Page not Found Page. Is there something I need to set somewhere so the pages work?

2) Also, I would like to create a default index page, but as it is now, it will use the first post as the index page. How can I set it up to show a specific page as the index page or how can I create an index page on the Pages area?

3) I'm using wp_list_pages to list out the navigation but it is in the wrong order. Is there any way I can re-order the pages as they appear in the navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2)** In the WP admin dashboard, on the left, click on: *Settings >> Reading* - Pick `A static page`. The page you pick for `Front Page` will be the default index page. `Posts Page` will be where your most recent blog posts are shown.

**3)** [The following lists the Pages by the `Order` value you can set for each page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Pages_by_Page_Order):

```
<ul>
   <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order'); ?>
</ul>
```

Also, searching and participating in the [Wordpress support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/) will probably help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much! Those are exactly the solutions I am looking for. I just wish I knew why my pages are linking to 404 error pages.